# AWS CloudFormation Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies <s3 bucket> in the Resources block of the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, jira

All that I am trying to do is follow this guide to get Atlassian services (Jira/JSM/Confluence) up and running on AWS https://aws-quickstart.github.io/quickstart-atlassian-jira/

I have followed all the details precisely and am currently at the point where I need to create the stack on cloudformation. When I paste in the .yaml url I get the error in the title, pointing me to an issue with the resources. I have looked through it and I'm not sure what the problem is, help would be appreciated.

```
Resources:
  VPCStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Sub
        - https://${QSS3BucketName}.${QSS3Region}.amazonaws.com/${QSS3KeyPrefix}submodules/quickstart-atlassian-services/templates/quickstart-vpc-for-atlassian-services.yaml
        - QSS3Region: !If
            - GovCloudCondition
            - s3-us-gov-west-1
            - s3
      Parameters:
        AccessCIDR: !Ref 'AccessCIDR'
        AvailabilityZones: !Join
          - ','
          - !Ref 'AvailabilityZones'
        ExportPrefix: !Ref 'ExportPrefix'
        KeyPairName: !Ref 'KeyPairName'
        PrivateSubnet1CIDR: !Ref 'PrivateSubnet1CIDR'
        PrivateSubnet2CIDR: !Ref 'PrivateSubnet2CIDR'
        PublicSubnet1CIDR: !Ref 'PublicSubnet1CIDR'
        PublicSubnet2CIDR: !Ref 'PublicSubnet2CIDR'
        VPCCIDR: !Ref 'VPCCIDR'
        BastionHostRequired: !Ref 'BastionHostRequired'

  JiraDCStack:
    DependsOn: VPCStack
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Sub
        - https://${QSS3BucketName}.${QSS3Region}.amazonaws.com/${QSS3KeyPrefix}templates/quickstart-jira-dc.template.yaml
        - QSS3Region: !If ["GovCloudCondition", "s3-us-gov-west-1", "s3"]
      Parameters:
        CatalinaOpts: !Ref 'CatalinaOpts'
        CidrBlock: !Ref 'AccessCIDR'
        CloudWatchIntegration: !Ref 'CloudWatchIntegration'
        ClusterNodeInstanceType: !Ref 'ClusterNodeInstanceType'
        ClusterNodeMax: !Ref 'ClusterNodeMax'
        ClusterNodeMin: !Ref 'ClusterNodeMin'
        ClusterNodeVolumeSize: !Ref 'ClusterNodeVolumeSize'
        CustomDnsName: !Ref 'CustomDnsName'
        DBEngine: !Ref DBEngine
        DBEngineVersion: !Ref DBEngineVersion
        DBInstanceClass: !Ref 'DBInstanceClass'
        DBIops: !Ref 'DBIops'
        DBMasterUserPassword: !Ref 'DBMasterUserPassword'
        DBMaxIdle: !Ref 'DBMaxIdle'
        DBMaxWaitMillis: !Ref 'DBMaxWaitMillis'
        DBMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis: !Ref 'DBMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis'
        DBMinIdle: !Ref 'DBMinIdle'
        DBMultiAZ: !Ref 'DBMultiAZ'
        DBPassword: !Ref 'DBPassword'
        DBPoolMaxSize: !Ref 'DBPoolMaxSize'
        DBPoolMinSize: !Ref 'DBPoolMinSize'
        DBRemoveAbandoned: !Ref 'DBRemoveAbandoned'
        DBRemoveAbandonedTimeout: !Ref 'DBRemoveAbandonedTimeout'
        DBStorage: !Ref 'DBStorage'
        DBStorageEncrypted: !Ref 'DBStorageEncrypted'
        DBStorageType: !Ref 'DBStorageType'
        DBTestOnBorrow: !Ref 'DBTestOnBorrow'
        DBTestWhileIdle: !Ref 'DBTestWhileIdle'
        DBTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: !Ref 'DBTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis'
        DeploymentAutomationRepository: !Ref 'DeploymentAutomationRepository'
        DeploymentAutomationBranch: !Ref 'DeploymentAutomationBranch'
        DeploymentAutomationKeyName: !Ref 'DeploymentAutomationKeyName'
        DeploymentAutomationPlaybook: !Ref 'DeploymentAutomationPlaybook'
        DeploymentAutomationCustomParams: !Ref 'DeploymentAutomationCustomParams'
        ExportPrefix: !Ref 'ExportPrefix'
        HostedZone: !Ref 'HostedZone'
        InternetFacingLoadBalancer: !Ref 'InternetFacingLoadBalancer'
        JiraProduct: !Ref 'JiraProduct'
        JiraVersion: !Ref 'JiraVersion'
        JvmHeapOverride: !Ref 'JvmHeapOverride'
        KeyPairName: !Ref 'KeyPairName'
        MailEnabled: !Ref 'MailEnabled'
        QSS3BucketName: !Ref 'jira-bucket-aws'
        QSS3KeyPrefix: !Ref 'QSS3KeyPrefix'
        SSLCertificateARN: !Ref 'SSLCertificateARN'
        TomcatAcceptCount: !Ref 'TomcatAcceptCount'
        TomcatContextPath: !Ref 'TomcatContextPath'
        TomcatDefaultConnectorPort: !Ref 'TomcatDefaultConnectorPort'
        TomcatEnableLookups: !Ref 'TomcatEnableLookups'
        TomcatMaxThreads: !Ref 'TomcatMaxThreads'
        TomcatMinSpareThreads: !Ref 'TomcatMinSpareThreads'
        TomcatProtocol: !Ref 'TomcatProtocol'
        TomcatRedirectPort: !Ref 'TomcatRedirectPort'
        BastionHostRequired: !Ref 'BastionHostRequired'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing the template parameters section. If you have the AWS CLI installed you can run `aws cloudformation validate-template` with either `--template-body file://jira-cfn.yaml`  or `--template-url https://path.to/your/cfn/template.yaml` to check for template errors. You can also run the validation from the CloudFront console if you go to the editor and load/paste in the template.

Running the below command to [validate the template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/validate-template.html) produced this output (i saved your template as jira-cfn.yaml in the current working directory):

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://jira-cfn.yaml

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies 
[
TomcatEnableLookups, 
DBIops, 
SSLCertificateARN, 
QSS3KeyPrefix, 
JiraProduct, 
TomcatMinSpareThreads, 
DBMaxWaitMillis, 
DBStorageEncrypted, 
BastionHostRequired, 
DBTestOnBorrow, 
DeploymentAutomationPlaybook, 
MailEnabled, 
DBMultiAZ, 
JiraVersion, 
QSS3BucketName, 
JvmHeapOverride, 
DBRemoveAbandoned, 
DBInstanceClass, 
DBMasterUserPassword, 
jira-bucket-aws, 
CloudWatchIntegration, 
ClusterNodeInstanceType, 
DBMinIdle, 
DBPassword, 
ClusterNodeMin,
DeploymentAutomationCustomParams,
DBStorage,
TomcatMaxThreads, 
InternetFacingLoadBalancer, 
DeploymentAutomationBranch, 
ClusterNodeMax, 
DBMaxIdle, 
TomcatAcceptCount,
DBStorageType,
DBEngine,
AccessCIDR, 
TomcatDefaultConnectorPort, 
DBMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis, 
DeploymentAutomationKeyName, 
TomcatRedirectPort, 
DBTestWhileIdle, 
HostedZone, 
CatalinaOpts, 
KeyPairName, 
CustomDnsName, 
TomcatContextPath, 
DBRemoveAbandonedTimeout, 
ClusterNodeVolumeSize, 
DBPoolMinSize, 
DBTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis, 
DBEngineVersion, 
ExportPrefix, 
DBPoolMaxSize, 
DeploymentAutomationRepository, 
TomcatProtocol
] in the Resources block of the template
```

Comment: I apologize if this is a silly question, but why does it throw an error for that? Looking at this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html it says that the section itself is optional. Why is it required in this instance? Are there specific parameters that it is looking for?

I'm just confused because the guides that I have found for setting this up don't include any information on changing the template aside from the bucket name, but I have been having tons of issues

Comment: Its only optional if you dont use parameters - your template does use parameters, and it cant find them - hence the error. You can either define the parameters in your template, or remove the references and replace with hardcoded values. (I would suggest defining the parameters rather than hard coding - but either will work).